# Create Devise user that belongs to a department

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to assign a user to a department.
I read through so many forums and can't seem to make anything work. Below are my models

```
# organization.rb
has_many :departments

# department.db
belongs_to :organization
has_many :employees
has_many :users, through: :employees

# employee.rb
belongs_to :department
belongs_to :user

# user.rb
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, 
  :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
has_many :employees
has_many :departments, through: :employees

# routes.rb
root "static_pages#index"
resources :organizations, except: :index do
  get 'departments/:id/signup', to: 'departments#department_sign_up'
  resources :departments do
    resources :employees, except: :index, shallow: true
  end
end
```

What I want to accomplish is to have either a form or a link to add a user on the `department#show` page.
So when the user is created, it will create a record in the employees table that links the user to the department. I have not idea where to even begin. My initial inclination is to create a `form_for [@department, @employee]` and have nested attributes for `fields_for` users with the *email*, *password*, *password_confirmation* attributes?

Any help will be much appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: was the answer useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple way to accomplish this is by creating the `user` and handing over the `department_id`.   Therefore I'd recommend creating an own route for `create_employee` to separate the logic (of course you can start separating even more by adding a new controller just for the creation of new department employees e.g. already nested under the departments resource to avoid using the hidden field).

But I just want to give you a hint:

```
# in department#show

= form_for(User.new, url: create_employee_path(
  = f.hidden_field :department_id

____________________

# in routes.rb

resources :users do 
  post 'create_employee', on: :collection
end
```

Then in the `users_controller.rb` you can create these objects in the following order:

1. User utilizing the `params[:user]` hash
2. Employee by using the handed in `department_id`

e.g. like this:

```
# users_controller.rb
...
def create_emlpoyee
  @department = Department.find(:department_id)
  @user = User.create(params[:user])
  # here you will want to check if the creation was successful
  ...
  if @user && @department
    Employee.create(user: @user, department: @department)
  end
  # here you can redirect to wherever you want
  redirect_to @user
end
```

This code can of course be improved, but it should show you the approach.

I hope that this will help you getting things done.

Comment: has this been helpful?